# SQL - Why Does This Happen?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

These are the [tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF8Oe.png) that I'm working with.
With that in mind, I want to showcase the Employees that are both a supervisor and a manager.

But when I used this

```
select e1.fname,e1.lname
from employee e1,employee e2,department
where e1.ssn=e2.super_ssn and e1.ssn = Mgr_ssn
```

This was the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlPqQ.png)
I know I can solve the problem with 'distinct', but I'm more interested to know why the output turned out like it did.

Comment: What do you think it should do?

Answer (score 1):

How about `exists`?

```
select e.*
from employee e
where exists (select 1 from employee e2 where e2.mgr_ssn = e.ssn) and
      exists (select 1 from employee e2 where e2.super_ssn = e.ssn) ;
```

Your query returns duplicates for two reasons.  First, presumably managers and supervisors have multiple employees below them.  You end up with rows for each such employee. Second, you have a cartesian product with `department`, which further multiplies the rows.  The `department` table is not used in the query.

Using `select distinct` is not a good solution in this case.  The database just ends up having to do a lot more work than necessary -- first to create the duplicate rows and then to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

add department matching clause in where like

```
 select e1.fname,e1.lname
 from employee e1,employee e2,department d
 where e1.ssn=e2.super_ssn and e1.ssn = Mgr_ssn and 
 d.Dnumber=e1.Dno
```